# Как прочитать многострочные данные из файла с указанного фрагмента до указанного фрагмента?

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Всех с наступающим!

Есть файл с содержанием:

```
Database: vip_stroitel
Table: material
[5 columns]
+-----------+-------------+
| Column    | Type        |
+-----------+-------------+
| doska     | tinytext    |
| brus      | tinyint(4)  |
| kirpich   | varchar(16) |
| sippanel  | varchar(16) |
| blol      | char(1)     |
+-----------+-------------+

Database: vip_stroitel
Table: smeta
[2 columns]
+----------+-------------+
| Column   | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| ypodpis  | tinyint(2)  |
| npodpis  | varchar(24) |
+----------+-------------+
```

> Нужно прочитать как то все строки (на C#) начиная с фрагментов:
>   "**Database: vip_stroitel**" до фрагмента: "**+-----------+-------------+**" и
>   каждую ложить в одну строку и собрать в string list.

1).Номера строк начальных и конечных фрагментов всегда разные. 
2).Количество таких таблиц с колонками всегда разное (Может быть одна а может быть и 10 и более таких таблиц в одном файле).
3).Количество символов на фрагментах тоже разные.

Как такое реализовать можно? из одной строки ток приходилась так выдирать нужные данные а с многострочными данными не приходилась работать , в гугле не чего подходящего под эту конкретную задачу не нашел инфу ,интересуют примеры , как такое вообще реализуется на C#...

Comment: Покажите, что должно быть в итоговом string list.

Comment: Должен получиться всего один stringlist или несколько - по числу таблиц?

Comment: Эти данные в одну строку каждый ток: 1 строка: "Database: vip_stroitel
Table: material
[5 columns]
+-----------+-------------+
| Column    | Type        |
+-----------+-------------+
| doska     | tinytext    |
| brus      | tinyint(4)  |
| kirpich   | varchar(16) |
| sippanel  | varchar(16) |
| blol      | char(1)     |
+-----------+-------------+"

Comment: 2 строка: "Database: vip_stroitel
Table: smeta
[2 columns]
+----------+-------------+
| Column   | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| ypodpis  | tinyint(2)  |
| npodpis  | varchar(24) |
+----------+-------------+"

Comment: эти две строки кладем  в один стринг лист (для дальнейшей обработки по именам таблиц уже выборка будет там идти)...

Comment: эм... все вроде элементарно, в чем имено загвоздка? Тэг регулярных выражений означает что надо обязательно через них решать?

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста с примером если можно, нет не обязательно регуляркой..

Comment: На выходе один `List<string>` или для каждой таблицы свой?

Comment: один List<string> да, выше отвечал же уже на этот же вопрос подробно)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "Database: vip_stroitel\n" +
                      "Table: material\n" +
                      "[5 columns]\n" +
                      "+-----------+-------------+\n" +
                      "| Column    | Type        |\n" +
                      "+-----------+-------------+\n" +
                      "| doska     | tinytext    |\n" +
                      "| brus      | tinyint(4)  |\n" +
                      "| kirpich   | varchar(16) |\n" + 
                      "| sippanel  | varchar(16) |\n" +
                      "| blol      | char(1)     |\n" +
                      "+-----------+-------------+";

        string[] strings = data.Split('\n');

        List<Tokens> tokens = new List<Tokens>();

        foreach(string st in strings) {
            if(CalcPalka(st) == 3) {
                var rez = GetTokens(st);
                if(rez.Token1!="Column") {
                    Console.WriteLine(rez);
                    tokens.Add(rez);
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    public static int CalcPalka(string st) {
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<st.Length;i++)     {
            if(st[i]=='|') {
             k++;   
            }
        }
        return k;
    }

    public static Tokens GetTokens(string st) {
        string[] tks = st.Split('|');
        return new Tokens() {
            Token1 = tks[1].Trim(' '),
            Token2 = tks[2].Trim(' ')
        };
    }   
}

public class Tokens {
    public string Token1 { get;set;}
    public string Token2 { get;set;}

    public override string ToString() {
        return Token1 + ": " + Token2;  
    }
}
```

Потестировать можно тут - https://dotnetfiddle.net/cdQyDD

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно, а нужно с указанием начального фрагмента: "Database: vip_stroitel"  (тоесть чтобы можно было казывать фрагменты) и конечного фрагмента: "+-----------+-------------+" и надо чтобы эти фрагменты тоже попали в список, тоесть включая эти строки: "Database: vip_stroitel\n" +
                      "Table: material\n" +
                      "[5 columns]\n обязательно...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta то есть вам значения из строк вытаскивать не надо?

Comment: @GeneratorSveta в вашем вопросе будет ещё проще, просто все строки поочереди прочитать и положить в список... без обработки... вы так хотите?

Comment: Надо все строки вытащить (значения) а не тока эти значения: doska - tinytext
brus - tinyint(4)
kirpich - varchar(16)
sippanel - varchar(16)
blol - char(1) включая и эти тоже: ""Database: vip_stroitel\n" +
                      "Table: material\n" +
                      "[5 columns]\n" и обязательно должна быть возможность указать  ключевик/фрагмент в моем случай начальный это: "Database: vip_stroitel" а конечный фрагмент это: "+-----------+-------------+" дело в том что таких таблиц там может быть много в файле...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta и на выходе вы получите ровно тот же файл что и имели... кроме того что пустые строки будут стёрты.

Comment: выше внимательнее пожалуйста прочитайте еще раз шапку отписал же там все конкретно и максимально подробно как мне казалось).

Comment: Эти строки читаем в одну строку: 1 строка: "Database: vip_stroitel Table: material [5 columns] +-----------+-------------+ | Column | Type | +-----------+-------------+ | doska | tinytext | | brus | tinyint(4) | | kirpich | varchar(16) | | sippanel | varchar(16) | | blol | char(1) | +-----------+-------------+"

Comment: а эти строки в новую строку 2 строка: "Database: vip_stroitel Table: smeta [2 columns] +----------+-------------+ | Column | Type | +----------+-------------+ | ypodpis | tinyint(2) | | npodpis | varchar(24) | +----------+-------------+"   
далее эти два полученных строки кладем в один стринг лист (для дальнейшей обработки, по именам таблиц уже выборка будет там идти дальше)...